agent chatbot command returns "refused to connect" in the browser
I've completed the setup instructions for Docs Agent. At the end I run agent chatbot, which starts up. When I go to the provided local URL in a browser, I get "This site can’t be reached" and "refused to connect".
The extra information says this is a proxy error, but I don't know enough about proxies to troubleshoot this. Google searches didn't help. I tried to see if I had the same problem with a localhost server on Python, but I didn't. Since these are analogous situations, I thought troubleshooting localhost would uncover something that would me fix this.
I'm doing all of this on Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL), WSL2 2204.3.49.0.
I've found a few Google results about proxy access to local websites. Only a few of them are new enough to match my version Windows. And as I said, proxy configuration is not my strong suit.

Can you check https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and share more details ?
